# Am i going to go have issues with this .recordcount() without .movelast?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

My VBA code appears to work just fine, or, I haven't found a problem as yet...
I did have a problem when I used `rs.movelast` where the `recordcount = 0`. So I have commented out the `rs.movelast` and my code works fine.

But, I am aware that when using `recordcount()` it is good practice to do a `.movelast` because the `recordcount` only counts what has been accessed.

My code:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(varSQL0, dbOpenDynaset)

'    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
'----create new-----
        Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="Supplier_Dnotes", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
              With rs1
                .AddNew
                ![Supplier_Dnote_Ref] = varDnoteRef
                ![Supplier_Dnote_date] = Forms!delivery_Note_Ex.Supplier_Dnote_date
                ![Created_By] = gLoggedIn
                ![Created_Date] = Date
                .Update
             End With
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Else
.....
```

will I ever have an issue with my `recordcount` if I exclude `.movelast`?

Is there an alternative method to try and avoid this potential problem?

I should add that I have indexed `supplier_dnote_ref` so if there was a problem, the new record shouldn't add because it already exits. Also, now I have indexed my table the `recordcount()` shouldnt exceed 1, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to use RecordCount, you should do a MoveLast.
But as you stated, it is a problem if you do not have any records.

But you do not have to find out the correct count, just if there are any records. An alternative method would be to use for your If-then-else "RecordCount = 0" this instead

```
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) then
   ' the record count is > 0
   'Code...
Else
   ' the record count is 0
   'Code...
End If
```

BOF means: Before the records

EOF means: After the records

that implies => EOF And BOF: There are no records

Comment: ah I see, that's an interesting way to look at it. I'll try that out! So I no longer need the `rs.movelast` because im not using `rs.recordcount`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I edited my answer, hoping it is more clear now.

Comment: I altered my code and it works perfectly! It was easier for me to use `If (rs.EOF and rs.BOF)` than using the `not`. Same thing I guess, I just didn't want to have to swap my `then` and `else` code around.

Comment: @asdev: just to avoid possible confusion: Datensatz = record. Not recordset and not dataset.

Comment: @Andre451: Haha, thanks for letting me know. Never recognized using Denglish here.

Comment: BOF: Beginning Of File, EOF: End Of File.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823092.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the movelast to add a record. It may only add some time to the operation for no purpose.